# CoreData not showing debug warnings when crossing NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: core-data

On my Xcode scheme I added this argument on launch:

> -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1

I'm now trying to purposefully mess up to see the debug error, but none appears. In my method I grab a random entity in a background task and post it in a notification:

```swift
PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask { context in
  let random = Int.random(in: 1 ... Int(max))

  let request = Number.fetchRequest()
  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %d", #keyPath(Number.value), random)
  request.fetchLimit = 1

  let entities = try! context.fetch(request),
  let entity = entities.first!

  let userInfo = ["object": entity]

  Notification.Name.example.post(userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

In the notification handler, I then purposefully cross MOCs:

```swift
guard let entity = note.userInfo?["object"] as? Number else {
  return
}

viewContext.perform {
  let message = entity.display ?? "WTF"

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    display = message
  }
}
```

`viewContext` is the one provided from the environment, which is different from the context that was used to query the entity, so why am I not getting a failure?

I know the launch flag was set correctly as I see this in the console at runtime:

> CoreData: annotation: Core Data multi-threading assertions enabled.

Comment: But you haven’t done anything to the object so viewContext is unchanged.

Comment: Something doesn’t match here. In your background fetch, you put a managed object in the dictionary. But when you receive the notification you have an `as? NSNumber`. That `as?` would fail and the rest of the code would not run.

Comment: @TomHarrington The entity type is `Number`